# How do I Slide up the Grid when the content above it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I guess, it is better if I show you what I tried.
So, I am working to build a weather app in order to learn https://material-ui.com/. 
I am trying to prototyping the animation how I see it in Google flights as
[image]

I tried to do this using `Grid`, `Fade` available in material-ui (I used latest `3.9.3`). 
However, in my version, even though I use `Grid`, when I hide the `AppBar` and the `Form` content, the grid beneath it, does not slide up. My version looks like 
[image]

As you might see, what I mean. So, how do I slide the content up?
I have shared my code at https://codesandbox.io/s/13q4mmm36q?fontsize=14

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fade will simply just change the opacity. It doesn't inherently set its height to 0 or become display: none after fading out.

Just use material-ui Collapse component on the Header.

Code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ooyxn96mo9

Documentation:
https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/

Comment: Oh man! This is so nice. This is exactly what I was looking for. How did you arrive at the use of `Collapse`, it is not in any of the demos. I am wondering, how can I find such nuggets myself. Also, I realized I do not need `Fade` anymore. See https://codesandbox.io/s/73wz207o9j

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help @Nathan

Comment: For animations, the https://material-ui.com/utils/transitions/ gives some nice detail about what mui offers.